# Separate arrayof obj in others sequentially

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, reduce

Trying to do a method to re-arrange an array to print in columns:

```
I have:
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

I need to have:
b = [1, 4, 7];
c = [2, 5, 8];
d = [3, 6, 9];
...
```

where numbers of others colums(b, c, d) could be variable.

Comment: what contains `e` and `f`? what have you tried?

Comment: What is the expected output? What have you tried?

Comment: Add more information

Comment: If you just want to get them as triples use a for next loop and crate NEW ARRAYS for b,c,d... Have also a look at the ARRAY push function. I think that is the function you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `Array#reduce` call that returns an array of arrays, and determine which array each item belongs to, using the remainder of the index.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var listCount = 3;

var [b, c, d] = a.reduce(function(lists, item, index) {
  lists[index % listCount] = lists[index % listCount] || [];
  lists[index % listCount].push(item);
  return lists;
}, []);

console.log(b);
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
```